# Set Default Page On Customizer Live Preview

Tags: theme-customizer, frontpage

I have wordpress site and set login page as static front page. If I go to theme customizer exactly it will use front page to show site live preview. How to change page live preview to another page? In this case I will use post page as live preview page in customizer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default URL being previewed is `home_url( '/' )`. When no `url` query parameter is present when opening `customize.php`, this is the preview URL that is used. You can override the previewed URL when there is no `url` query parameter to supply a different default using something like this:

```
add_action( 'customize_controls_init', function() {
    global $wp_customize;
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['url'] ) ) {
        $wp_customize->set_preview_url( get_permalink( 1 ) );
    }
} );
```

Comment: but when I make a change, it goes back to the front page

Comment: @Prast I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: when I make a change in customizer, the page preview goes back show the front page, not the preview URL that I have set anymore.

Comment: @Prast not for me. What control are you changing in your test?

Comment: @WestonRuter he means that after changing options customizer does a full refresh and loads home page even though url points to the custom page. Works fine with partial refresh.